# pig ERROR 1200: null when using fs commands

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

while running pig in mapreduce mode im occuring really strange error.

The pigscript.pig contains....

```
x= load 'hdfs://file.avro' USING AvroStorage();
some transofrmations...
fs mv src/file dest/file;
```

up to this point all works fine, but script continues as

```
y = load 'hdfs://file2.avro' USING AvroStorage();
```

While executed previous command i got error bellow. I double check and the file2.avro is there ... stored in the HDFS.

When I quit pig and re-run the code from the line

```
y = load 'hdfs://file2.avro' USING AvroStorage();
```

all works fine.

Any idea?

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: null

Failed to parse: null
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:201)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1707)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1680)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:623)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1063)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:558)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage.getAvroSchema(AvroStorage.java:298)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage.getAvroSchema(AvroStorage.java:282)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage.getSchema(AvroStorage.java:256)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:89)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:901)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3568)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
        ... 16 more
================================================================================
```

Comment: You can't have a pig loading statement depend on a file that is not available when the Pig frontend is processed. Pig frontend will try to read file2.avro to get the schema so the execution plan can be generated. If the file only exists after some part of the script would be executed this is not possible.

Comment: doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: both file exists there before execution.